# React Redux wait for ui to update in a function/lifecycle hook

Tags: reactjs, redux

Here is my componentDidMount:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.userDetailsSetState({
      loading: true
    });
    this.loadInitData(this.props.computedMatch.params.id);
  }
```

The loadInitData does some timetaking stuff so I want the loader to appear before this function call completes.
Currently this is not happening and it seems that the UI is rendered only after the loadInitData completes.
How do I make sure that loading element appears BEFORE the loadInitData starts execution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use async await actions and wait for sucess result when
.then success result false your loader

Comment: thanks man. But i'll have to see if using async await in react lifecycle hooks is a good idea. also whether dispatches return a promise so that they can be awaited.